# How to get value from a nested hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have this nested hash with three answer parts:

[image]

I want to get:

```
q2a.text= "Purchasing experience"  
q2a.answer="4"  
q2b.text= "Design on the product"  
q2b.answer="4"  
q2c.text="Quality of the product"  
q2c.answer="4"
```

but I don't know how to do it.

```
{
            :question_text => "Please rate the following based on your overall experience:",
    :question_export_value => nil,
            :question_type => "10",
                   :answer => [
        [0] {
                    :answer_part => "Purchasing experience",
                  :answer_column => "4",
                    :answer_text => "4",
                   :answer_other => nil,
            :answer_export_value => nil,
                 :answer_comment => nil
        },
        [1] {
                    :answer_part => "Design on the product",
                  :answer_column => "4",
                    :answer_text => "4",
                   :answer_other => nil,
            :answer_export_value => nil,
                 :answer_comment => nil
        },
        [2] {
                    :answer_part => "Quality of the product",
                  :answer_column => "4",
                    :answer_text => "4",
                   :answer_other => nil,
            :answer_export_value => nil,
                 :answer_comment => nil
        }
    ],
           :question_score => "0",
            :question_code => nil,
          :question_number => "2"
}
```

Comment: Please post your data, not just a screenshot of your data.

Comment: Don't try to game the system by adding worthless text. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, and "[mcve]". Stack Overflow isn't a discussion board or chat system. Every question is a new article in an online reference book, with associated answers as people try to help solve the problem, so we expect questions to be as concise and detailed as necessary to describe the problem. Fluff and "Hash Here's the hash: I need to add more details otherwise it won't allow me to post. some other details. some other details." waste space.

Comment: We'd really like to see your attempt to solve the problem. Without evidence of effort it looks like you haven't tried and want us to write the code for you. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/261593 would be useful.

Comment: Thanks for you advice. I don't really know coding. I'm on H1b Visa. If I don't make it work. I'll be laid off and will lose legal status immediately. I'll be deported next Jan. If I had another choice, i won't be here ask basic question.

Answer (score 3):

When in doubt consult the [docs](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html). Also, in the future, please use code snippets instead of screen shots, that way I can copy paste from your example.

I'll give you a brief overview of ruby hashes. First of all lets create your hash. I will use a shortened version because I don't want to retype your entire hash.

```
my_hash = {
  question_text: "Please rate the following based on your overall experience",
  question_export_value: nil,
  question_type: 10,
  answer: [
    {
      answer_part: "Purchasing experience",
      answer_column: "4",
      answer_text: "4"
    }
 ]
}
```

To get the the answers you need to access you hash with the appropraite key: `my_hash[:answer]`.`my_hash[:answer]` actually points to an array of hashes, notice the brackets instead of the braces. So to get to the first answer you would use `my_hash[:answer].first`. This points to the first hash in the answers array. You may pull values out of this hash using the desired value's key. to get to "Purchasing experience" you would use

```
my_hash[:answer].first[:answer_part]
```

to get the answer text "4"

```
my_hash[:answer].first[:answer_text]
```

Comment: my_hash[:answer].second[:answer_part] this goes to the second hash?

Comment: No, at the my_hash[:answer] level, the Object is an Array (where each element is a hash): https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-first Arrays have .first  and .last. The normal thing would be to use .each or .map to iterate through a list of items.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but the question is a little confusing since the payload in your screenshot and the bit of code you pasted don't really match at all. Think you'll want to learn some basic Ruby syntax with hashes and arrays:

http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html

http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html

Specifically check out the `[]` methods.

I'm going to try and respond based off of the payload. But basically you're working with a hash where one of the values in the hash is an array, and each of the elements in an array is another hash.

So, starting from the main hash you have something like this

```
answers = payload[:answer] # where payload is the hash you posted
q2a = answers[0]
q2b = answers[1]
q2c = answers[2]
puts q2a[:answer_part], q2a[:answer_text] # prints "Purchasing experience" and "4"
puts q2b[:answer_part], q2b[:answer_text] # prints "Design of the product" and "4"
puts q2c[:answer_part], q2c[:answer_text] # prints "Quality of the product" and "4"
```

So to sum up, grab the array with the key `:answer` from the hash, index into the array for the data you want, and then use the proper keys to grab your data.